# Why roslaunch couldn't show the ROS_INFO message?

Tags: roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

node_test.cpp

```
 #include "ros/ros.h"
 
 int main(int argc, char **argv)
 {
    //ROS的初始化
    ros::init(argc, argv, "basic_node");
    ROS_INFO("%s","Hello World!!");
    //讓ROS進入無窮迴圈，但能進行事件處理
    ros::spin();
    return 0;
 }
```

basic.launch

```
 <launch>
    <node pkg="basic_node" name="basic" type="basicNode"/>
 </launch>
```

Just run is ok:

```
 sam@/home/sam/code/ros/node/basic_node$ ./bin/basicNode 
 [ INFO] [1316858268.471014429]: Hello World!!
```

Why I run with roslaunch is not ok?

```
 sam@/home/sam/code/ros/node/basic_node$ roslaunch basic_node      basic.launch 
 ... logging to      /home/sam/.ros/log/afeaec82-e691-11e0-9f34-20cf30a2382f/roslaunch-sam-Syst     em-Product-Name-11412.log
 Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
 Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
 Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.
 
 started roslaunch server http://sam-System-Product-Name:41031/
 
 SUMMARY
 ========
 
 PARAMETERS
  * /rosversion
  * /rosdistro
 
 NODES
   /
     basic (basic_node/basicNode)
 
 ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311
 
 core service [/rosout] found
 process[basic-1]: started with pid [11430]
```

How to show message on roslaunch?

Thank you~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11302/why-roslaunch-couldn%27t-show-the-ros_info-message?/) by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2570 on 2011-09-23

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Sam,

Just add output="screen" to your node line in the launch file, like this:

```
<launch>
   <node pkg="basic_node" name="basic" type="basicNode" output="screen" />
</launch>
```

--patrick

---

Originally posted by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) with karma: 4046 on 2011-09-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 24

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Liuche](https://answers.ros.org/users/32466/liuche/) on 2017-11-01**:
It's help for me thanks!!!!